# How to fix apt-get upgrade error code 1

Tags: debian, apt-get, stretch, debian-stretch

OS: Debian 9 (Stretch) 4.9.0-6-amd64

When i tried to launch apt-get upgrade command from cmd return this error:

```
ribbo@Debian:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Lettura elenco dei pacchetti... Fatto
Generazione albero delle dipendenze       
Lettura informazioni sullo stato... Fatto
Calcolo dell'aggiornamento... Fatto
0 aggiornati, 0 installati, 0 da rimuovere e 0 non aggiornati.
17 non completamente installati o rimossi.
È necessario scaricare 0 B/1.816 kB di archivi.
Dopo quest'operazione, verranno occupati 0 B di spazio su disco.
Continuare? [S/n] s
dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto python-attr (--configure):
 il pacchetto si trova in uno stato di inconsistenza critico: è consigliato
 installarlo nuovamente prima di tentare la configurazione.
dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto python-lzma (--configure):
 il pacchetto si trova in uno stato di inconsistenza critico: è consigliato
 installarlo nuovamente prima di tentare la configurazione.
dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto python-colorama (--configure):
 il pacchetto si trova in uno stato di inconsistenza critico: è consigliato
 installarlo nuovamente prima di tentare la configurazione.
dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto python-pyasn1-modules (--configure):
 il pacchetto si trova in uno stato di inconsistenza critico: è consigliato
 installarlo nuovamente prima di tentare la configurazione.
dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto python-gobject-2 (--configure):
 il pacchetto si trova in uno stato di inconsistenza critico: è consigliato
 installarlo nuovamente prima di tentare la configurazione.
dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto python-incremental (--configure):
 il pacchetto si trova in uno stato di inconsistenza critico: è consigliato
 installarlo nuovamente prima di tentare la configurazione.
dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto python-parsley (--configure):
 il pacchetto si trova in uno stato di inconsistenza critico: è consigliato
 installarlo nuovamente prima di tentare la configurazione.
dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto python-constantly (--configure):
 il pacchetto si trova in uno stato di inconsistenza critico: è consigliato
 installarlo nuovamente prima di tentare la configurazione.
dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto python-zope.interface (--configure):
 il pacchetto si trova in uno stato di inconsistenza critico: è consigliato
 installarlo nuovamente prima di tentare la configurazione.
dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto python-psutil (--configure):
 il pacchetto si trova in uno stato di inconsistenza critico: è consigliato
 installarlo nuovamente prima di tentare la configurazione.
dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto python-serial (--configure):
 il pacchetto si trova in uno stato di inconsistenza critico: è consigliato
 installarlo nuovamente prima di tentare la configurazione.
dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto python-pil:amd64 (--configure):
 il pacchetto si trova in uno stato di inconsistenza critico: è consigliato
 installarlo nuovamente prima di tentare la configurazione.
dpkg: problemi con le dipendenze impediscono la configurazione di asymptote:
 asymptote dipende da python-pil; comunque:
  Il pacchetto python-pil:amd64 non è ancora configurato.

dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto asymptote (--configure):
 problemi con le dipendenze - lasciato non configurato
dpkg: problemi con le dipendenze impediscono la configurazione di python-gtk2:
 python-gtk2 dipende da python-gobject-2 (>= 2.21.3); comunque:
  Il pacchetto python-gobject-2 non è ancora configurato.

dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto python-gtk2 (--configure):
 problemi con le dipendenze - lasciato non configurato
dpkg: problemi con le dipendenze impediscono la configurazione di texlive-full:
 texlive-full dipende da asymptote; comunque:
  Il pacchetto asymptote non è ancora configurato.

dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto texlive-full (--configure):
 problemi con le dipendenze - lasciato non configurato
dpkg: problemi con le dipendenze impediscono la configurazione di python-pil.imagetk:amd64:
 python-pil.imagetk:amd64 dipende da python-pil (= 4.0.0-4); comunque:
  Il pacchetto python-pil:amd64 non è ancora configurato.

dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto python-pil.imagetk:amd64 (--configure):
 problemi con le dipendenze - lasciato non configurato
dpkg: problemi con le dipendenze impediscono la configurazione di gimp:
 gimp dipende da python-gtk2 (>= 2.8.0); comunque:
  Il pacchetto python-gtk2 non è ancora configurato.

dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto gimp (--configure):
 problemi con le dipendenze - lasciato non configurato
Si sono verificati degli errori nell'elaborazione:
 python-attr
 python-lzma
 python-colorama
 python-pyasn1-modules
 python-gobject-2
 python-incremental
 python-parsley
 python-constantly
 python-zope.interface
 python-psutil
 python-serial
 python-pil:amd64
 asymptote
 python-gtk2
 texlive-full
 python-pil.imagetk:amd64
 gimp
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

My source.list file is: */etc/apt/source.list*

[image: /etc/apt/source.list]

Launching apt-get update works OK:

[image: sudo apt-get update]

I've seen a lot of guides on how to fix the problem without any result.
I've tried to fix the problem through synaptic and cmd but no luck in both cases.

Thank a lot for help!

Comment: It might be helpful to translate the error messages or change the system language, as the language on StackOverflow is english.

Comment: Please report a bug  : [How to report a bug in Debian using reportbug](https://www.debian.org/Bugs/Reporting)